# What is kitchen sink overflow valve called, and is there an alternative?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

My kitchen sink does not have an overflow, but the basket has an overflow connection which is capped off with a screw on cap which encloses a shallow cup shaped rubber diaphragm, which appears to exist to allow air to escape. It is now rather old, and starting to fail, resulting in flooding under the sink. Two questions: 1. what is the rubber valve called? 2. is there a more reliable system that I can use? See photos below:

[image: the overflow cap with diaphragm]

[image: the basket with overflow pipe]

Comment: Would get a complete screw on cap as the same size as that screw on ring and rubber cap.

Comment: I guess the leak was from the rubber end piece, and I would get a blank cap to seal off the overflow pipe as it is normally unnecessary.

Comment: Are you sure that was not a type of air admittance valve? That doesn’t look like the AAV’s I have worked with but it’s location up high it makes it a possibility.

Comment: It looks like it is meant to allow air to escape rather then allow air in (the valve is placed in the ring such that it’s externally concave. It is a double sink, by the way, so the other sink has one too, so I figure that if I seal off this one, then air can still escape fro the other.